# pointannotation is not working in android

Tags: react-native, react-native-mapbox-gl

I am using react-native-mapbox-gl library for map and trying to render draggable marker.

Following code for render point annotation:

```
<MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
                                ref={ref => (this.annotationRef = ref)}
                                key="idInpsectionTool"
                                id="idInpsectionTool"
                                draggable={true}
                                //coordinate={[54.606937, 24.370718]}
                                coordinate={this.state.inspectionCoordinate}
                                onDragEnd={this.onInspectionToolDragEnd}
                            >
                                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                                    <Image source={require("../assets/pin.png")} style={{ height: 60, width: 60 }} onLoad={()=>this.annotationRef.refresh()} />
                                    <Icon name="location-sharp" type="Ionicons" style={{ color: "green", fontSize: 60 }} />
                                </View>
                            </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>
```

It is working perfectly in ios and in android it is not rendering behind the map. i can see while loading map. once map loaded i can't see in in android only.

Comment: I just disable raster basemap. now it is working.

Comment: how can i use pointannotaion with raster layer

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I have a similar issue with emulator and real device (are different issues).

1. Run and install the app
2. The images on PointAnnotation are completely invisible
3. Change the height and width in real time and the image appears.

Comment: I don't have issue real device and emulator. It is behave same in both. In Android it is  going under other layers, that is issue.

Comment: They are only shown at certain times. If I change the style instead, it works in debug. You mentioned about layers. I have one layer

Comment: I have many layers

Comment: What is you version of Mapbox?

Comment: react-native-mapbox 8.5

Comment: I use mapbox 8.6 beta. I see now "BETA". I can try to fly back to 8.5, like u.